# Would it be possible for Microsoft to phase out the Win32 API in future versions?

Tags: windows, winapi, operating-system

I like to use Win32, even in the age of .Net, MFC and touch. My co-worker said to me that it might not be possible to use the Win32 API in future versions of Windows (after Windows 9), because Microsoft might deprecate it.

However, this seems impossible to me, because windows itself uses so much of that API. If they got rid of the low level Win32 C library, the operating system would itself stop working, and they would have to recode a great portion of the Operating System (Not to mention all the code that would be broken).

Anyway, I don't know much about this stuff, does anyone have any technical understanding on if this is impossible or not?

Also, note that I'm ***not*** asking if windows *will* deprecate the low level API in the future, I know that's speculative. My specific question regards how **feasible** it would be for Microsoft to do this, assuming they wanted to.

Comment: Have been hearing this crap since .NET 2.0, and Vista had to hit the market from these "co-workers"

Comment: They might not deprecate Win32/Desktop but they could lock it down to a set of whitelisted programs (Office, Visual Studio, Windows utilities), effectively the same thing for the LOB developer.

Comment: Don't forget that Win32 is relevant on desktops only. WinRT spans across other architectures. Win32 might not get deprecated, however, the relevance of desktops may diminish.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as "primarily opinion based" because it's asking us to speculate on what Microsoft might do. Only they can answer this, not us.

Comment: Well [API Sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/apiindex/windows-apisets) are one answer to this question already. If you target a modern Windows version the resulting binary may no longer statically import from `kernel32.dll` or `user32.dll` but will instead use a versioned and scoped DLL name. This is one of the first steps to decouple it from the system. Doesn't mean the API is going away, but means it won't be as closely coupled.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It would be technically possible, but only if they wanted to lose all of their market share. A lot of internal LOB of apps are coded against the Windows API (Even .Net sits on top of it, but is not strictly dependent on it, as shown by Mono). WinRT, the Next Big Thing in Windows 8 is built on top of the Windows API

Win32 (which is the Windows API itself, along with all the other various parts) is a subsystem built on top of the NT Kernel. I imagine it would be possible to make a version of the kernel where that is disabled (I'm rather sure the OS/2 subsystem is no longer there, the POSIX layer is though, as the userland for that is installable).  A picture from Wiki to illustrate what I'm talking about:

[image]

I don't see any reason why it wouldn't be possible to implement the .Net runtime or WinRT as a subsystem. However, the amount of work that would be probably doesn't make sense, as they would have to re-implement a lot of what's in Win32 (That's probably the reason why, in the 20 years the NT kernel has existed, only these three subsystems have been released). For the scope of what they would need to re-implement, you can look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Win32 It pretty much includes from Winsock to DirectX.

But, even if they were to implement newer kernel subsystems, the first release without the Windows API would be bought by no one, as none of their old apps would run (Even if they implemented the new subsystems, then a few versions later, remove the Windows API, there would still be apps depending on it, and would break in the next version, causing horrible press, and then no one would buy it. Look at what happened to Vista.

Comment: Very true, and it would be quite a change from the efforts they put in backward compatibility. Ask Raymond Chen http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/

Comment: From my observations, the Raymond Chen camp has been losing ground recently at Microsoft. It's very sad to watch. That said, I don't think the Win32 API is going away any time soon. Yes, they could replace it with something else since, as you mention, it's just a software layer on top of the kernel. But it's very difficult to understand what the advantage of that might be. And even if the Windows team was just bored, they'd never get it approved, because **everything** currently relies on Win32 somewhere under the hood. WinForms, WPF, WinRT, the list goes on...

Comment: This is a really interesting subject, that is relevant to many peoples futures. I wish It got more traction. And I wish Raymond Chen gave more of a response :(

Comment: I think you completely misunderstood what a subsystem is in terms of the above diagram. The only reason for the long removed OS/2 subsystem (which anyway only ever supported a subset of OS/2 applications) was a joint venture. Search for "NT OS/2". The POSIX subsystem was the response to US government procurement guidelines which mandated POSIX compatibility. If you ever dabbled with Interix or SFU you _know_ that the compatibility is a source-level compatibility. Resulting binaries were PE files, just with a different subsystem mentioned in their optional header.

Comment: And no, the WSL (no matter if WSL1 or WSL2) does _not_ fit into the above list of subsystems either, despite the expanded version of the acronym mentioning a "subsystem". Functionally it probably fits into the category, albeit with more heavy _specialized_ kernel mode support than previous subsystems (new kernel objects and drivers got introduced to enable what WSL does). The fact that in WSL (1) you execute unaltered ELF through a system call translation layer (implemented in a driver) as opposed to specific-subsystem PE files tapping into generic NT services is a good clue, too.

Answer (score 1):

Arguably Microsoft has been on it for some time now -- including at the time you asked. [API Sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/apiindex/windows-apisets) are a good indicator of that.

However, the question is what *exactly* you mean by *phasing out*.

For example: what, if the idea isn't to *get rid* of the Win32 API at all but to decouple it more from the system, promote other APIs more (e.g. WinRT) and slowly move those away from the Win32 API under the hood? Keeping the Win32 as a facade to legacy applications nevertheless ... Deprecating but not removing.

Yes, it is very much technically possible (already mentioned in the existing answer). Hidden behind such innocent page titles as ["New Low-Level Binaries"](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/win7appqual/new-low-level-binaries) from the time of Windows 7 is the bombshell fact that APIs have been rearranged for quite some time now.

For example functionality that used to be in `kernel32.dll` on older Windows versions has moved to `kernelbase.dll`. Older applications still have static imports from `kernel32.dll` in their import tables, though.

Newer ones not so much. When targeting a modern Windows version (e.g. 8 onwards) using Microsoft's Visual C++ toolchain, it would no longer contain static imports from `kernel32.dll` or `psapi.dll` but instead from a range of API set DLLs. Examples are:

- `api-ms-win-core-console-l1-1-0.dll`
- `api-ms-win-core-datetime-l1-1-0.dll`
- `api-ms-win-core-debug-l1-1-0.dll`
- `api-ms-win-core-errorhandling-l1-1-0.dll`
- `api-ms-win-core-file-l1-1-0.dll`, `api-ms-win-core-file-l1-2-0.dll` & `api-ms-win-core-file-l2-1-0.dll`
- `api-ms-win-core-handle-l1-1-0.dll`
- `api-ms-win-core-heap-l1-1-0.dll`
- `api-ms-win-core-interlocked-l1-1-0.dll`
- `api-ms-win-core-libraryloader-l1-1-0.dll`
- `api-ms-win-core-localization-l1-2-0.dll`
- `api-ms-win-core-memory-l1-1-0.dll`
- `api-ms-win-core-namedpipe-l1-1-0.dll`
- `api-ms-win-core-processenvironment-l1-1-0.dll`
- `api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-0.dll` & `api-ms-win-core-processthreads-l1-1-1.dll`
- `api-ms-win-core-profile-l1-1-0.dll`
- `api-ms-win-core-rtlsupport-l1-1-0.dll`
- `api-ms-win-core-string-l1-1-0.dll`
- `api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-1-0.dll` & `api-ms-win-core-synch-l1-2-0.dll`
- `api-ms-win-core-sysinfo-l1-1-0.dll`
- `api-ms-win-core-timezone-l1-1-0.dll`
- `api-ms-win-core-util-l1-1-0.dll`

Just from looking at the DLL names you can already deduce some of the traits also mentioned in the above linked article on [API Sets](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/apiindex/windows-apisets). It starts with a sort of namespace and then splits into different "topics". Microsoft calls everything before the `.dll` extension **contract names**. Technically Microsoft has treated Win32 APIs as contracts already, if you look at the pains they've gone through to ensure compatibility to legacy applications in modern Windows. Raymond Chen's book "The Old New Thing" as well as his blog of the same name is a testament to that.

Still these DLLs expose functions the old way, but only well-defined sets that will probably not change across versions. And internally through system facilities (links below) and DLL function forwarders they end up resolving to functions in `kernelbase.dll` and other new low-level binaries.

While more details of API Sets (introduced in Windows 7) have transpired over the years, they existed back when you asked your question. I don't know why this topic didn't come up in the existing answer or comments. But most certainly the API Sets are one answer to your question: yes, it is feasible. And it's underway in the sense of decoupling the Win32 from the lower layers.

That said: I would like to point out that with all the compatibility efforts Microsoft has put in in the past, I don't expect the Win32 API to go away. Keeping in mind that OLE became COM, COM became COM+ and COM+ became .NET, I think outright removal of the Win32 API is unlikely. Instead I expect it to become versioned (see the DLL names above). This will also aid efforts to support -- literally -- generations of legacy applications down the road. This is a two-sided sword, however. Via this method it is also easier to confine developers (and consequently applications) to individual versions of the API Sets.

PS: when looking at the topic one should also keep the history of the Win32 API in mind. Some of the functionality hails from Win32s times (i.e. Windows 3.11 etc. with a 16-bit DOS under the hood), whereas other parts hail from Windows NT. If you are well-acquainted to the individual functions, you can easily make an educated guess where it came from based on argument types and parameter names. And I don't mean the `A`/`W` duality here!

### Further reading

- If you're interested in some gory details, read [here](https://lucasg.github.io/2017/10/15/Api-set-resolution/) and [here](https://www.geoffchappell.com/studies/windows/win32/apisetschema/index.htm)

  - A tool akin to the old Dependency Walker by the author of the first source above, a tool capable of dealing with API Sets: [Dependencies](https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies)